# Anyone know why element.class doesn't work as a selector in the text editor Brackets?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using Jquery, to select elements within a div by using the syntax `$(element.classname)` or `$(element#idname)`. Does anyone know why am I unable to select the elements in this case?

For example, the class name is "foo" and the element is p.
`$("p.foo")` doesn't work in Brackets but `$(".foo p")` would work.

Here is my html as well and my Jquery code.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styling.css">
    </head>


    <body>
        <div class="foo">

            <p>Do you like waffles?</p>


        </div>
    </body>

    <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p.foo").on("mouseenter", function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without seeing your HTML we cannot help you. The selector difference would only be caused by the HTML be rendered differently than you think it is.

Comment: Maybe your editor does not support that selector?

Comment: Thanks for editing the HTML in to the question. The answer is because the `foo` class is on the parent of the `p`, not the `p` itself. I'd suggest you research how jQuery and/or CSS selectors work.

Comment: Thank you Rory for the clarification! :)

Answer (score 3):

Because by using the syntax `$("p.foo")` you are literally stating that you are looking for the `<p>` tag with the class `foo` not the element inside of that class.  If you are trying to target an element inside of the class `foo` like in your example you need to use the syntax `$(".foo p")`.  Now you are stating that you are looking for the `<p>` tag inside of the class `foo`.

So `$(".foo p")` and `$("div.foo p")` would target the exact same element being the `<p>` tag inside of the div with class of `foo`.

Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Steve! Makes sense after I thought about the difference between the two syntaxes :)